# Code - help leapyear

Tags: c++, leap-year

I've got an issue with my code here. The program is supposed to count seconds/year. I've managed to fix the leapyear but couldn't fix the normal year. Hope someone could fix it. (it's a function that's called to main)

**Note**

- h=hours
- d=day
- ye=year
- m=month
- s= seconds
- t= total seconds
- t2= leapyear

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void max_s()                            
{
    unsigned long long s=1; 

int h=s*60;

    int d=h*24; 
    int m=30; 
    int ye=12;
    long long t=s*h*d*m*ye; 
    long long t2=t+86400;
    bool y,n;
    y=true;
    n=false;
    cout<<"leapyear? 'y' for yes 'n' for no "<<endl;
    cin>>y||n;
    if(y=true)
    {
        cout<<"leapyear:"<<t2<<endl;
    }
    else
    {   
        n=false;
        cout<<t;
        cout<<"seconds/year "<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `cin>>y||n;` to do?

Comment: the user is supposed to ethier type in y(yes) or n(no) for leapyear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(y=true)` This is **always** `true` since it'll be evaluated to the assigned value.

Should be:

`if(y)`

Actually this is a very good reason to see why we don't write `== true` when comparing `boolean`s. You can easily misspell one `=` causing assignment instead of comparing.

Furthermore, what exactly is `cin>>y||n;`?

Tip that saves lives: As @FredLarson mentioned, enable warnings (`-Wall`) and you'll get a warning about that.

Comment: Adding the `-Wall` compile flag (or equivalent for compilers other than g++) should warn of the accidental assignment too.